# How to find an exponential generating function if we know a usual generating function?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Suppose we know a usual generating function of a sequence $a_0,a_1, a_2 \ldots :$
$$
f(x)=a_0+a_1 x+a_2 x^2+\cdots,
$$

**Question.** It is possible to find an exponential generating function for the sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2 \ldots  $ if we know its usual generating function?

Comment: Essentially, you want to compute the [Hadamard product](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15671/which-hadamard-products-of-generating-functions-are-known) of $f$ with $e^x$. In general finding formulas for Hadamard products is difficult or impossible, and I don't know of any reason to believe that this one is an exception...

Comment: Keep in mind that if one converges the other doesn't need to. $\sum k!\frac{x^k}{k!}$ converges for $-1<x<1$, but $\sum k!x^k$ only converges at $x=0$.

Comment: This question is also discussed at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289377/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C$ be any contour in the complex plane surrounding the origin counter-clockwisely once.
We have this little identity
$$\frac{x^k}{k!} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{e^{xt}}{t^{k+1}} dt$$

Given an OGF $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$, we can "formally" construct the corresponding EGF as

$$\begin{align}
f_{\rm EGF}(x) \stackrel{def}{=} \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k \frac{x^k}{k!}
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k \left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{e^{xt}}{t^{k+1}} dt\right)
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_k e^{xt}}{t^{k+1}} dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C} f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\frac{e^{xt}}{t} dt
\end{align}
$$
The integral on RHS depends on $C$. To find the correct EGF, we need to use the right contour.

Let us use the case $a_k = 1$ for all $k$ as an example. We know the corresponding OGF $g(x)$ is $\frac{1}{1-x}$. Substitute this in above formula, the corresponding EGF becomes

$$g_{\rm EGF}(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{1}{1 - 1/t} \frac{e^{xt}}{t} dt
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{e^{xt}}{t - 1} dt
$$
In order for the sequence $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ converges to $g(x)$,we need $|x| < 1$. This means $$|1/t| < 1 \quad\iff\quad |t| > 1\quad\text{ on }C.$$
As a result, the contour $C$ we need is the one which include $t = 1$ in its interior. Using such a contour, we find the correct EGF for this example:
$$g_{\rm EGF}(x) = {\rm Res}( e^{xt} ; t = 1 ) = e^{x}.$$

Comment: Thank you!  What about the inverse tranformation?

Comment: @Leox In principle, one can use the identity 
$\displaystyle\;\;n! = \int_0^\infty t^n e^{-t} dt\;\;$
to construct a formal inverse
$$f(x) = \int_0^\infty f_{\rm EGF}(xt) e^{-t} dt$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)$ be the ordinary generating function and $\mathcal{L}$ be  the Laplace transform.  Then  the EGF  $g(z)$  has the form 
$$
g(z)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{z} f(z)\Big |_{z=\frac{1}{z}}\right)
$$